# openCV: How can I increase performance on image processing?

Tags: c++, opencv, flir

I am using USB camera from FLIR and make some processing on every captured frame.

Unfortunately, I managed to process only 10 frames per second (or even 5 frames while running in "debug" configuration).

How can I increase the performance?

PC: intel core i5-5200u (Broadwell) 2.7GHz 8 GB RAM

OS: windows 10

Language: c++

image processing library: openCV ver 3.4.0

VS: 2015 (vc14)

FLIR API: Spinnaker

This is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Spinnaker.h"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;
using namespace Spinnaker;

#define GAUSSIAN_SIZE               11

Mat ConvertToCVmat(ImagePtr pImage)
{
    int result = 0;
    ImagePtr convertedImage = pImage->Convert(PixelFormat_BGR8, NEAREST_NEIGHBOR);

    unsigned int XPadding = static_cast<unsigned int>(convertedImage->GetXPadding());
    unsigned int YPadding = static_cast<unsigned int>(convertedImage->GetYPadding());
    unsigned int rowsize = static_cast<unsigned int>(convertedImage->GetWidth());
    unsigned int colsize = static_cast<unsigned int>(convertedImage->GetHeight());

    //image data contains padding. When allocating Mat container size, you need to account for the X,Y image data padding. 
    Mat cvimg = cv::Mat(colsize + YPadding, rowsize + XPadding, CV_8UC3, convertedImage->GetData(), convertedImage->GetStride());
    return cvimg.clone();
}

void measureTime(void)
{
    static int frameNumber = 0;
    frameNumber++;
    if (frameNumber == 24)
    {
        static int64 e2 = 1;
        static int64 e1 = 0;
        e2 = getTickCount();
        double time = (e2 - e1) / getTickFrequency();
        e1 = getTickCount();
        printf("Proccessed %d frames in %f seconds\n", frameNumber, time);
        frameNumber = 0;
    }
}

void run(CameraPtr pCam)
{
    // Initialize camera
    pCam->Init();

    // Set trigger off, software, and then on again: 
    pCam->TriggerMode.SetValue(TriggerModeEnums::TriggerMode_Off);
    pCam->TriggerSource.SetValue(TriggerSourceEnums::TriggerSource_Software);
    pCam->TriggerMode.SetValue(TriggerModeEnums::TriggerMode_On);

    // Set aqcuisition mode to continuous and start: 
    pCam->AcquisitionMode.SetValue(AcquisitionModeEnums::AcquisitionMode_Continuous);
    pCam->BeginAcquisition();

    // Retrieve the next image:
    namedWindow("image", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
    while (1)
    {
        pCam->TriggerSoftware.Execute();
        ImagePtr pResultImage = pCam->GetNextImage();

        // convert to openCV format
        Mat frame = ConvertToCVmat(pResultImage);
        pResultImage->Release();

        // convert to one channel
        cvtColor(frame, frame, COLOR_RGB2GRAY);

        // Gaussian blur:
        Mat imageProc1 = frame;
        GaussianBlur(frame, imageProc1, Size(GAUSSIAN_SIZE, GAUSSIAN_SIZE), 0, 0);

        // find max value:
        double minValue, maxValue;
        Point minIndex, maxIndex;
        minMaxLoc(imageProc1, &minValue, &maxValue, &minIndex, &maxIndex);

        // Draw circles: 
        circle(imageProc1, maxIndex, 29, Scalar(0, 0, 255), 3);

        // Measure time:
        measureTime();

        imshow("image", imageProc1);

        if (waitKey(1) >= 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    // Deinitialize camera
    pCam->EndAcquisition();
    pCam->DeInit();
}

int main()
{
    // Retrieve singleton reference to system object
    SystemPtr system = System::GetInstance();

    // Retrieve list of cameras from the system
    CameraList camList = system->GetCameras();

    // Retrieve pointer for the camera: 
    run(camList.GetByIndex(0));

    // Clear camera list before releasing system
    camList.Clear();
    // Release system
    system->ReleaseInstance();
}
```

Comment: Consider moving everything from `ConvertToCVmat()` to `circle()` to a different thread. Measure how long your acquisition takes without any processing, and measure how long your processing takes without any acquisition. Then think how you can *"hide"* the processing behind the acquisition using one or more threads.

Comment: You are not only processing image but you are capturing and displaying as well. The best thing to do is to run asynchronously. Use a separate thread to capture the images and store in queue and another thread to process and maybe another thread to display (some camera can display the image as part of the acquisition step). You may need to implement a multi-threaded producer-consumer algorithm (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer–consumer_problem or goo.gl/h53TCt). Your FPS will then be limited by the slowest of image capture, processing and display.

Answer (score 0):

Image processing (especially batch processing) is a typical use case for [multi threading](https://solarianprogrammer.com/2011/12/16/cpp-11-thread-tutorial/).

Multi threading gives an enormous speed boost, because multiple images (up to the numer of cores of your machine) can be processed at once. Of course, the library you use has to be explicitly thread-safe (I don't know if that's the case for OpenCV, please refer to the manual - but I assume it is, because libraries don't make much sense nowadays without being thread-safe. Nevertheless, some of them need special defines to compile thread-safe), and also your own code has to be thread-safe.[thread-safe](https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/03/cpp11-concurrency-part1-start-threads.html). This is not very easy to learn, but it's definitely worth the effort.

Another way to achieve great speed is to use the GPU for such tasks. GPUs are highly parallel and even faster than multi threading on a CPU. Your used library has to support GPU processing (again, refer to the manual), or you will have to write the GPU code yourself (e.g. with [OpenCL](https://anteru.net/blog/2012/11/03/2009/index.html)). And you will need a powerful graphics card with a good GPU.